# $\forall x\in\mathbb{R},,$ if $x^{2}$ is rational, then $x$ is rational.

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification

This is my attempt at this question. Is this correct?

$\forall x\in\mathbb{R},,$ if $x^{2}$ is rational, then $x$ is rational.

This statement is false.
Using counterexample, let $x=\sqrt{2}$. Since $x^2 = (\sqrt{2})^2 = 2$ is a rational number and $x = \sqrt{2}$ is an irrational number, this statement is false.

Comment: Yes, your argument is correct.

Comment: An integer times an integer is always an integer.  A rational number times a rational number is always a rational number.  For these, we say "the integers are closed under multiplication", "the rational numbers are closed under multiplication" respectively.  This shows a counter example for irrational numbers, i.e. there exists an example of two irrational numbers whose product is not irrational.  We usually refer to this result by saying "the irrational numbers are *not closed* under multiplication."

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to say "it's false" twice, but your reasoning is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in using a counterexample to effectively disprove a "for all" claim, but the main thing I would suggest here is to improve how you have given your answer/solution. Mathematical communication/writing is not a trivial matter; indeed, [entire books](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1447165268) have been written on the matter (linked to book is simply one I would recommend). That being said, the following is how I would answer your question in a more polished manner.

---

> **Claim:** $(\forall x\in\mathbb{R})(x^2\in\mathbb{Q}\to x\in\mathbb{Q}).$
>
> *Counterexmaple*. Consider $\sqrt{2}\not\in\mathbb{Q}$ [note: you should either prove that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational or make reference to a proof]. Then $(\sqrt{2})^2=2\in\mathbb{Q}$, contradicting the claim. $\blacksquare$

Comment: I am not sure I agree with using formal language to state the theorem (and I have done a fair bit of logic!). I always think implications should be stated in words for some reason, maybe it's just me.

Comment: @Asvin More or less, I think it depends on OP's level. I think in the circumstance under consideration it is pretty fitting.